# Delete file from list [PHP]

Tags: php

I have this code that shows me every file in a directory:

```
foreach (glob("*.*") as $filename) {
    echo $filename."<br />";
}
```

I also want this to echo a link to delete said listed file, but I do not know how. Could someone please help me out?

Comment: You can put a button besides the name and if the button is pressed you can send the file name as GET parameter

Comment: Look into PHP's [unlink()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)